# How do I turn off Enhanced Security Configuration in Internet Explorer on Windows Server 2008?

Tags: internet-explorer

This is my own personal sandbox development machine, and I'm getting a bit annoyed about the Internet Explorer Enhanced Security Configuration getting in the way of simple downloads.

Is there a way to turn this off?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Look in the security part of Server Manager. [This article](https://web.archive.org/web/1/http://blogs.techrepublic%2ecom%2ecom/datacenter/?p=255) shows how to do it.

Comment: Thanks Jon - so, go to Server Manager, under Security Information choose "Configure IE ESC", and select appropriately from the dialog that's displayed. (/me mutters - "IE ESC" - and that's supposed to be discoverable? Meh!)

Answer (score 0):

The process is a little different for Windows Server 2016:

1. Click *Start Menu*, and open *Server Manager*
2. On the left navigation pane, select *Local Server*
3. Find *IE Enhanced Security Configuration* and click on *On*
4. Turn off IE ESC for Administrators and/or for Users and click *OK*
5. Restart Internet Explorer

See the [complete instructions with screenshots here](http://tunecomp.net/disable-internet-explorer-enhanced-security-configuration-windows-server-2016/).